# How to predefine the required format of a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I currently build a dashboard in Excel to track forex trades. One worksheet is for adding new trades to the database. Within this worksheet i have several fields that the user needs to fill in order to add the trade to the database. Now I want to avoid that the user inserts wrong data (regarding format) in the cells and therefor crashes the outputs from the database later on.

How can I define such criteria via VBA? For example the field date to have the format YYYY-MM-DD and the field Trading Volume XX,YY so the user can't (accidentally) insert X,YY etc. For dropdown fields it is easy by defining the inputs within the dropdown menue itself, but i need some solution for the manually filled cells.

I will then define a msgbox to pop up and inform the user to meet the required input formats.

Thank you very much in advance!

Some key words would help me, I can then get into deeper it and code it by myself.

Comment: Similarly like this line would work for you. `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using code could you not use data validation and force entry of a date, numeric value etc.?

If you define the cell format to be custom 'yyyy-mm-dd' then apply data validation with a defined date range Excel will auto format it for you even if they enter dd/mm/yyyy and alert if an invalid entry is added.

Then for a belt and braces approach run a routine at Save that will mimic what your database will do and alert if there is still invalid data see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave

I would also lock down the sheet to avoid users adding rows / columns or moving your cells around.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lzGN.png)

Comment: Thank you, will try this approach! Any option to close cases here?